# android check if an activity was started from an action or from another activity?

Tags: android

In my manifest file, I have an activity declaration which looks something like this:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

This activity is obviously launched on application start. User can navigate from this activity to another activity and from that one to another etc.
In another activity, I start MainActivity by using 'startActivity' method, ie. something like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(AnotherActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

In my `MainActivity` (in onCreate() method maybe), can I determine whether an activity was started from a action of from another activity? Is there something like "launcher listener"? I would like to avoid putting any extra content in the intent.
Can I simply put `String s = getIntent().getAction();` in onCreate method and check whether it is has a value of MAIN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the stock android launcher does send `Intent.ACTION_MAIN` as as the action. However, you can't be sure that some other launcher will have the same behaviour. Your best bet will be to pass some extra data with the Intent.